# Python Jython global variable usage

Tags: python, scope, jython, global

I have a problem with my understanding of python global variables and their correct usage. The first bit of code works fine, the second bit throws the exceptions "NameError: global name 'chosen' is not defined". I am sure I am missing something simple here, but I can not see what it is.

I want to associate a Listener with each of many event generators and then use the getChoices method to get a dictionary of the choice made be each generator.

```
#Working code
class Listener1():
  chosen = "0"
  def __init__(self, choice):
    self.choice = choice

  def actionPerformed(self, event):            
    global chosen
    chosen = self.choice

  @staticmethod
  def getChoices():
    return chosen

e1 = Listener1('evt1')
e1.actionPerformed('abc')
print Listener1.getChoices()
```

Failing code

```
class Listener2():  
  chosen2 = {'a':-1}
  def __init__(self, choice):
    self.choice = choice
    global chosen2
    chosen2[self.choice] = 'unset'

  def actionPerformed(self, event):
    val = event
    global chosen2
    chosen2[self.choice] = val

  @staticmethod
  def getChoices():
    return chosen2

e2 = Listener2('evt2')
e2.actionPerformed('def')
e3 = Listener2('evt3')
e3.actionPerformed('ghi')
print Listener2.getChoices()
```

Footnote:
the Listener2 class works correctly if I move the first reference to the global variable **chosen2** to the line before the class definition instead of the line after.

Thanks to the answers below, code rewritten as:

```
class Listener3():
  chosen3 = {}
  def __init__(self, choice):
    self.choice = choice
    if choice is not None:
        self.chosen3[self.choice] = 'unset'

  def actionPerformed(self, event):
    val = event
    self.chosen3[self.choice] = val

  def getChoices(self):
    return self.chosen3

e1 = Listener3('evt1')
e1.actionPerformed('abc')
e2 = Listener3('evt2')
e2.actionPerformed('def')
e3 = Listener3('evt3')

print Listener3(None).getChoices()
{'evt1': 'abc', 'evt2': 'def', 'evt3':'unset'}
```

And apart from being much simpler, is now working perfectly.

Comment: Question answered. Thank you to Martijn, Matthew and heyden for not being rude to me in missing this most obvious problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `global` does what you think it does. In both cases `chosen` and `chosen2` are *class* variables, not globals.

But when you declared `chosen` as a global and assigned to it, python happily *created* a global variable (separate from `Listener1.chosen`) and stored your value.

But for `chosen2` you are not assigning anything to it; you are trying to treat it as a dict instead, but you didn't create the variable by assignment so that fails.

You want to use `self.chosen2` instead; as a class variable, it'll be available to all instances of `Listener2`. You can also use `Listener2.chosen2`. For `chosen`, you can use `Listener1.chosen` to refer to it. The `global` keywords can be dropped altogether.

In any case, declaring a variable as `global` does not mean *outside of my current scope*. It means *at module scope* instead, so always outside of your functions, classes, and method definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the same error:

```
global chosen2 #you're not creating chosen2, just saying you're about to create it, and when you do - it should be a global variable
chosen2[2]=2 #chosen2 has yet to be defined so how can you set anything?
```

You're trying to set a property of an as yet undefined object `two`, first you must say whether you want it to be a list or dictionary (or otherwise).

```
global chosen2
chosen2={}
chosen2[2]=2
```

*As mentioned I don't think you want this to be global (as you want be able to create class instances with different values of chosen2!*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `global` here. In your examples, `chosen` and `chosen2` are class attributes. Instead of:

```
global chosen
chosen = self.choice
```

You'd just write:

```
self.chosen = self.choice
```

When you define `chosen2` before the class, you're actually defining it in the scope that `global` refers to. When you define it *within* the class scope, it's a class attribute that is shared by all instances.

*Update:* as pointed out, straight assignment to the class attribute isn't what you want, as it'll create a new attribute on the instance which masks it on the class. But in your `Listener2` example, this will be fine:

```
def actionPerformed(self, event):
    self.chosen[self.choice] = event
```

Here, you're not overwriting `.chosen`, but adding an item to the dictionary it refers to, so the class will keep a record of the most recent event for each listener.

Comment: `self.chosen = self.choice` will create an instance variable, not what the OP wants. Each instance will have it's own copy, instead of sharing the state.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced he wants a class attribute here, but whatever.

Comment: It might not be the best idea, but I'm fairly certain that's what the OP tried to achieve. :-)

Comment: I was hoping pointing in the right direction would be enough, but I've updated now for clarity :)